# Why can't I write container.iterator?

Tags: c++, syntax

Why can't I write code neither like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> m;

    m.iterator it = m.find("five");
    //~~~^~~~~
    // nor like this:
    m::iterator it = m.find("eight");
}
```

Comment: You can write `auto`.

Comment: or `std::map<std::string,int>::iterator`

Comment: Because the syntax of the language doesn't allow it?

Comment: `decltype(m)::iterator` also works.

Comment: What's the reason which of the language doesn't allow it?

Comment: @Gordem, it is all about how the language works.

Comment: because this isn't a member. it's a nested class or typedef

Comment: Because the `.` in the `m.iterator` syntax is specified as accessing a member of the object, and `iterator` is not a member of `m` - it is a type definition that is nested in the (templated) type definition named `std::map`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't write `m.iterator`, because `iterator` is not a data member or member function, you can't use member access operator (i.e. `operator.`) for it. (`iterator` is a nested type name.)

You can't write `m::iterator`, because `m` is not a class name or namespace name, you can't use it with scope operator (i.e. `operator::`).

You can use `auto` (since C++11) to let the type to be deduced.

```
auto it = m.find("five"); // the type would be std::map<std::string, int>::iterator
```

Or get the type by `decltype` (since C++11).

```
decltype(m.begin()) it = m.find("five");   // the type would be std::map<std::string, int>::iterator 
decltype(m)::iterator it = m.find("five"); // same as above
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the iterator declaration as:

```
std::map<std::string, int> m;

auto it = m.find("five"); //since c++11 OR:
std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it2 = m.find("five");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the help of `using` here:

```
std::map<std::string, int> m;

// creating an alias of std::map<std::string, int> as 'n'
using n = std::map<std::string, int>;

// the second method given in your code
n::iterator it = m.find("eight");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I write container.iterator?

Because the language doesn't allow it.

> What's the reason which of the language doesn't allow it?

Because the designers of the language decided so.

In particular, they chose that scope resolution operator and member access operator do not overload the same punctuator. And they chose that variables are not scopes.

---

For completeness, here is a commonly used, correct way to write it:

```
auto it = m.find("eight");
```